# Moment failed to work with webpack (typescript + babel)

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Just as the [demo](https://github.com/sleagon/broken-ts-babel), when i add moment to the project, bundle built by webpack failed, once i remove the moment it is ok.

Note: the module in tsconfig.json is set to es6, which is exactly what i need, when switch it to commonjs, it is ok too.

I am told you guys are acitve here, thanks very much to you~~~

Comment: just git clone the project and try ```npm run build``` which will open the html by default.

Comment: I got no problem with your code ?

Comment: there is no error during compiling, however, the index.js is broken and can not be executed in browser. @DarknessZX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After got it running and disable minify mode, I saw that problem is how you using moment. You can use this config to see your unminify code problem:

```
entry: './src/index.tsx',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'lib'),
    filename: 'index.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(tsx|ts)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
        // We no not want to minimize our code.
        minimize: false
  },
```

After change, I got error `moment is not a function`. So it's a problem when webpack bundle and how moment export their function
https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/959
You can fix it by

```
const moment = require('moment')
```

to use the function as document or

```
moment.toString()
```

to just got the current time.

Or change options in tsconfig like in https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/

Comment: Emmm, actually i can not push all our developer to write code as you said, is there any way to overcome this problem without modify the code style? As shown in [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), we should could import moment. Anyway, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @shanyy you can just change `import * as moment from 'moment'` to `const moment = require('moment')` to use it normally

Comment: That will not save the problem, once anyone wrote code like ```import * as moment from 'moment'```, the project will crash without any readable error information.

Comment: @shanyy I have updated another options. The least problem is just change the way you import moment, you have to communicate to show them that the problem is exist and they have to change to fix that.